# Live search from database table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search, mysql

I have wordpress site. I made custom table and sotred values in one row. Now I made admin menu and added input field into it.

```
<input id="location1" type="text" />
```

I need to predict search while I type. So if I have stored word "computer" and "company" and I start typing comp, under search box results computer and company should appear.

I added jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
$( "#location1" ).autocomplete({
        source: "ajaxurl",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
    </script>
function search_ajax_callback_function() {
    // Implement ajax function here
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_db', 'search_ajax_callback_function' );
```

and I have php:

```
$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "database";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM locations";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        }
    } else {

    }
    $conn->close();
```

So does anybody knows how to add predictions to my search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in php it needs to be:

```
$query = 'SELECT Location FROM locations';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $rows[] = $r['Location'];
 }
```

and jquery ui autocomplete:

```
$("#location1").autocomplete({
            source: <?php echo json_encode($rows);?>,
// this part is only if you want to force autocomplete select
change: function (event, ui) {
    if(!ui.item){
        $(event.target).val("");
    }
}, 
focus: function (event, ui) {
    return false;
} //end autocomplete force
        });
```